# Magento + Netsuite Integration

Tags: magento, netsuite

My goal is to fetch all the product from netsuite and dump it in magento.

I'm trying to fetch all the inventory records from netsuite using PHPToolkit. Currently, i am able to retrieve 1000 records but there are almost 10,000 records that i should fetch and put to magento.

Is there any best way of achieving my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **searchMoreWithId**

Check the url for details http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/de/d06/class_net_suite_service.html#a024f8c9b7120c549d72e1d05b6676f6f

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all pages of the result set.

You have a couple of nodes in the response data to help you. These 2 will help you figure out how many pages you have in the results and what the current page is:

```
$currentPage = $searchResponse->searchResult->pageIndex;
$totalPages = $searchResponse->searchResult->totalPages;
```

You also have this node in the response, which gives you the ID # of the search:

```
$searchId = $searchResponse->searchResult->searchId;
```

After the initial page of records, loop through all pages by calling "Search More", and make sure you increment the current page variable as you go along.

```
$currentPage++;
$searchMoreReq = new SearchMoreWithIdRequest();
$searchMoreReq->searchId = $searchId;
$searchMoreReq->pageIndex = $currentPage;
$searchResponse = $NSservice->searchMoreWithId($searchMoreReq);
```